# Two ListFragments synchronization

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I have two `ListFragment`s on the screen. One on the left side there is is a file structure - folders. On the right side there is a `ListFragment`, each element of that list is a paragraph of text with a title on the top.

Now, the file structure on the left is an effective copy of all the paragraphs' titles, but taking into account the hierarchy, so it is not flat.

Now when I click a folder on the left I want a list on the right to be scrolled to/display the paragraph that has that folder name as a title. I could try using `setSelection(POSITION);` method but  how would I find out the bloody POSITION then? The POSITION in the left list is not equal to the POSITION in the right one.

Dear all, any ideas on this one? It is more of a design question.

I would be really grateful for any help xxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android developers guide states:

> All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated
>   Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.

**Situation**

ListA in FragmentA and ListB in FragmentB. Clicking on an item in ListA should scroll ListB to the correct position.

**(Possible) Solution**

- Communication between Fragments is done by the FragmentManager.
- Use an ArrayAdapter for both your lists. This means that an ArrayList will be given with the constructor as kind of datasource. Let's call them ArrayListA and ArrayListB
- When you click on your item in ListA, you have to search in ArrayListB for the title and give back the position. Once you have the position, you can set the position of ListB.